# Ansible playbook passing variable to next play

Tags: variables, ansible, parameter-passing

I have built a playbook in ansible that creates 2 groups of ec2 instances.

In a second playbook, I want that the first play lists the existing group to the user so the user can choose one. Then in a second play, use this group in hosts

```yaml
---
- name: playbook
  hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: groupvar
      prompt: "Select a group"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: task 1
      debug:
        msg: "{{ groupvar}}"

- name: Another play
  hosts: "{{ groupvar }}"

  # ...
```

How can I pass on the value of `groupvar` to the second play in this playbook?

Answer (score 2):

*Note: make sure you are not simply re-inventing the existing `--limit` option of the `ansible-playbook` command line*

---

As you found out, `vars_prompt` do not survive the play they're declared in. In that case you have to use `set_fact`. Here is an example using your above code as a starting point:

```yaml
- name: playbook
  hosts: localhost
  vars_prompt:
    - name: groupvar
      prompt: "Select a group"
      private: no
  tasks:
    - name: task 1
      debug:
        msg: "{{ groupvar }}"

    - name: Save value in a fact for current host
      set_fact:
        groupvar: "{{ groupvar }}"

- name: Another play running on above chosen group
  # Remember we have set the fact on current host above which was localhost
  hosts: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].groupvar }}"

  # ... rest of your play.
```

Comment: Thanks Zeitounator. If in another playbook, I had created some ec2 instances and added them to ansible groups using add_hosts, would that survive the play? When I execute the code above,

Comment: So your question is in fact: "can I address a group/hosts I added to the in-memory inventory with `add_host` in an other playbook?". The answer is no. And in your particular case, you want to use a dynamic inventory.  See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that... I think I might be missing something because when I call ansible-inventory -i my.aws_ec2.yml --list I get
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/ubuntu/my.aws_ec2.yml as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

Comment: What do you expect from dumping such an error without context in a comment? This is a different problem from your above question, the message clearly indicates it could not parse your inventory file and no one has a clue of what it looks like. **After carefully checking and debugging on your side**, ask a new question with a [mre]